# ASP.NET MVC vs Spring MVC

Tags: java, .net, asp.net-mvc, comparison, spring-mvc

Can anyone please make a comparison of `ASP.NET MVC` vs `Spring MVC`.

Which technology is better in performance, productivity, maintenance, features,...

Regards,
sirmak

Comment: I was tempted to do a longest common subsequence run on them, since they're in quotes. Turned out I was too lazy, though.

Comment: If you know Java, the Java option is better. If you know .NET, the .NET option is better. Anything else is totally subjective opinion.

Comment: I agree with Rex.  However, if you know both platforms well enough, it does come down to a question of features and purposes.

Comment: I don't think this needs to be closed, if someone wants to take the time to write an answer, by all means!  It's not subjective and argumentative, it's just a comparison.

Comment: @Rex M, your answer is the best.

Comment: This question is to subjective.

Comment: **Actually Comparision between frameworks is not important but, What we can do with that Framework is most Important...**

I am also agree with #@RexM answer because If you know .Net you will go with ASP.Net MVC4, If you know Java you will go with SpringMVC+Hibernate and If you know PHP you will go with Zend Framework 1.x/2.x + ORM ( Doctrine ) + ExtJS or jQuery/Bootstrap. It is up to you what you know. MVC is same at any time just languages and additional featured may be changed somehow.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's hard to say which one is "better"....

First - there's the whole underlying "Java vs. .NET" argument - you can't really compare the frameworks ignoring this.

The whole history of web development in Java with "heavyweight" J2EE apps vs. "lightweight" Spring apps.  That in Java there are a ton of web frameworks (MVC and not, open-source vs. Sun-developed) and that Spring MVC had a lot to be based on.

And on the ASP.NET MVC side - the whole history of ASP -> ASP.NET -> ASP.NET MVC.  And the lack of *widely-used* non-Microsoft .NET frameworks - web or otherwise.

Now into the opinionated part...

I'm somewhat the opposite of @Luke101 as I've worked mostly with Spring MVC and very little with ASP.NET MVC.

I have to say I prefer MVC-style web development over component-based web development.

I have worked with JSF, which is similar to ASP.NET webforms. (I have to say I liked ASP.NET more than JSF - though this probably has more to do with the maturity of each framework when I used it, and tools available - I used JSF 1.0/1.1 and just Eclipse with no JSF specific support vs. ASP.NET 2.0/.NET 3.5 with Visual Studio 2008.)

As far as MVC frameworks I prefer Spring MVC - but that's entirely because I'm just more familiar with Java - language-wise and development-wise, as opposed to ASP.NET MVC / C# /.NET.  Also, Spring MVC requires Spring, and I like to develop using Spring's whole IOC pattern and use things already integrated into Spring.

I haven't tried using Spring.NET and ASP.NET MVC - maybe this would be similar to Spring MVC / Spring / Java.

In the Spring.NET repo there are some examples of integrating Spring.NET into ASP.NET MVC [version 3](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-net/tree/master/examples/Spring/Spring.Mvc3QuickStart), [version 4](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-net/tree/master/examples/Spring/Spring.Mvc4QuickStart) and [version 5](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-net/tree/master/examples/Spring/Spring.Mvc5QuickStart).

Answer (score 30):

I've tried both Spring and ASP.NET MVC frameworks. I found ASP.NET MVC easier to use, mainly because of significantly less configuration code (both xml and java/c#) in ASP.NET framework required to get things worked. In Spring you can get all the features ASP.NET MVC has by default, but be prepared to write many xml/java configuration code and maybe use some third party tools.

Among strong benefits of Spring are integrated IoC, ORM (mainly Hibernate for me) and transaction managment support.

Comment: This answer is mostly obsolete since the introduction of Spring Boot.

Comment: @Apokralipsa yep, spring boot looks very impresive - even no servlet container required)

Comment: @Apokralipsa  I can write MVC style apps with Spring boot, out of the box? Like ASP.NET MVC

Comment: @kilonet "even no servlet container required" - what does this mean? I don't need a web server i.e. like IIS? It has a built in web server?

Comment: @Abdul yeah. Go to http://start.spring.io/ and in dependencies select `Web`. It will generate a simple project that will have the MVC part of the framework and the embedded Tomcat server.

Answer (score 7):

This question has been around for a couple years, but I think you guys should stop thinking in terms of who is more familiar with asp or Java. In todays world it doesnt matter, I can hire a few code monkey's like us anywhere or I for example can write in both and anyone can pick up either in a matter of days, I think in a large scale scenario, what matters more is what is affordable, hosting on Windows/asp platform or Linux/Java, sure the easy of technology matters, but we arent comparing C programming to Java. I guess everyone agree they both are competing technologies. What do you rather invest into? Questions to that nature. 
For example I think hosting on a linux platform will be cheaper.

Answer (score 5):

ASP.NET MVC is pretty young but very powerful and fast. I have rewritten all my web applications from webforms to asp.net MVC. I have seen a noticable difference in the cpu utilization and the amount of ram being used. I think if I built my projects from scratch in MVC it would take a little longer then in webforms.

I really can't comment on spring as I have never used it. But, here is an interesting discussion on the whole java and microsoft thing.

http://philip.greenspun.com/bboard/q-and-a-fetch-msg?msg_id=000tcP

Answer (score 4):

Here's a PDF I found titled [Comparision Between Spring and ASP.NET Frameworks](http://www.psl.cs.columbia.edu/classes/cs6125-s11/presentations/2009/Presentation_Preeti_Malik.pdf), but I don't agree with some of the ASP.NET MVC comments like:

- Offers only one view format (.aspx pages)
- Tight coupling between URL and Class action name

It appears to be a quickly done slide deck for a university course, and not something by someone that has developed in each framework.

Comment: wow, a comprehensive comparison, thank you.

Comment: the link is not woking anymore

Comment: It looks like that same document is now available here: http://www.philadelphia.edu.jo/courses/ADO.NET/Presentation_Preeti_Malik.pdf

Comment: lol still the link is not working

Comment: Here's a working link (as of today) : http://www.psl.cs.columbia.edu/classes/cs6125-s11/presentations/2009/Presentation_Preeti_Malik.pdf

Comment: That link incorrectly states that you can only have one Controller with ASP.NET (not true with ASP.NET MVC, you can create any amount you want). and that most configuration is maintained with source code (hello?  app.config?  web.config??)